# How to center image on hover? (currently hovering on the left hand side)

Tags: css, image, background-image, center, centering

I've been looking on stackoverflow and trying different things, but nothing seems to work.

I'm out of ideas.

I have this menu here (for now, my links are inactive)

```
<nav id="nav-left-en">
            <nav id="services-en">
                <a href="#">Services</a>
            </nav>

            <nav id="mission-en">
                <a href="#">Our Mission</a>
            </nav>

            <nav id="contact-en">
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>

</nav>
```

And I would like that, upon hovering over it the image centers. My text itself is not  aligned to the center (hence the problem I have -  but I do not want to center it to the center, because the hover has to look the same everywhere). Right now, the hover appears aligned-left with the text itself.

This is the last css I tried. I've tried others, but I'm out of ideas. I've had no luck with stackoverflow and other places that were looking at this type of things.

(note: I have also tried with background-image as well)

```
background: url('images/hover.jpg')  no-repeat;
            border: 0;
        width:150px; /* this is the width I want it to be. The text itself is 115px*/
        color:white;
        background-position: -58px 0px ;
```

**EDIT**

I edited the code... and this is exactly what I am looking for, EXCEPT that there is an extra space on each side. For example, Let's say that I have 120px in width for each item, well, the color should be 150px in width. Thus, an extra 15px on each side.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('nav').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).css({"background-color":"#108040"});
            }, 
                function () {
                    $(this).css({"background-color":""});
                }
    );

});
```

Perhaps this code will help you in understanding what I'm looking for. In this case, I decided to use js (as it is shorter than the css that does the same thing)

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle with what you have so far...including live links to the image(s).

Comment: I would also mention that you should not be wrapping each link in a `nav`...use a div instead..if you must but it's probably not necessary.

Comment: You can very easily solve this with a onmouseover js event that adjusts the positioning as needed.

Comment: JS probably isn't necessary but until we see the image it's hard to comment further.

Comment: I hope I uploaded it correctly to jsfiddle :/

If not, lemme know.


http://jsfiddle.net/u8hfw/

Comment: The image is just a green block...could you not just use a background color? Why does it need to change position?

Comment: That specific picture is for testing. I also prefer it is would be a picture (as it would useful coding in the future). See, right now, the green block is aligned to the left, which is not good at all. I need it to be aligned to the center, so that every item is properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Well this "centers" the background image horizontally on hover. The quality of the supplied code is however too poor to visually determine whether this result is what you expect.

http://jsfiddle.net/u8hfw/5/

But you do realize that there are syntax errors in both supplied HTML and CSS in your fiddle (
http://jsfiddle.net/u8hfw)? I've corrected them in the above fiddle just to make it work. Beside of that, the use of HTML attributes, as well as CSS rules and selectors is very bad. You may end up with a lot of bugs later and spending a huge amount of time debugging them.

Just a few advices:

- Try to avoid `!important` in your CSS.
- Use `id` HTML attribute only if you need to target a specific element. Otherwise use a `class` attribute. For example use same class on all nav `<nav class="menu-item">` and apply a single CSS rule `.menu-item{ *your css here* }`
  -

To find syntax errors, validate your code using [W3C validation service](http://validator.w3.org/unicorn/)

Comment: Concerning the corrections, I've been in too much pain (tooth problem) to make much sense of whether or not I had pasted all the right code. I took a look at your code, but that isn't at all what I was looking for. Perhaps you misunderstood. Some of the text is hidden (which it shouldn't). What I was looking for is having the text aligned to the left, but then the background (imagine hovering over all of the 3 links) would look to be centered to the longest piece of text. I hope I'm not sound like an ass right now (the pain is pretty bad). Btw, what are the more than, less than signs about?

Comment: I modified the OP to better explain what I meant.

Comment: You sound all right. Firstly, the text is not hidden. You just colored it white, on a white background. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/u8hfw/6/) I have added some CSS to show that. The `#element>nav` means: all direct children of `#element` with tagname `nav`. It isn't the most suitable selector here. Just used it in the example to avoid changes in your HTML. In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/u8hfw/8/) fiddle I gave your nav a class name, as it supposed to be. Is it what you try to achieve? Honestly the jQuery function you provided confuses me more. It just changes the background color back and forth

Comment: There are a lot of rules in your CSS which break the consistency in your layout, and I don't know wheter you need them or is it a mistake. For ex. `background-position: -58px 0px;` on your background image, the two first `nav` have `padding-bottom:24px;` while the third doesn't. The first `nav` has `background-position:0 0;`. There rules break a lot, and I have no idea if you need them.

Comment: I actually changed everything so they would be equal. I guess I should I posted that as well (the pain was too much I guess - thanks for bearing with me). http://jsfiddle.net/u8ctH/1/ In this fiddle, the js isn't kicking in for some reason, but on my site, the BG of "Nous rejoindre" is green, & the text is white. The green BG is the same length everywhere as "Nous rejoindre", as the BG length is 115px for each of them. It starts at the beginning of each letter, & ends at 115px to the right. Concerning what I said yesterday nite, don't pay attention to that lol. I wasn't thinking straight.

Comment: If you check out the fiddle, pretend you can see the green background on hover (I don't know why js doesn't kick in on the fiddle. Maybe it's not suppose to because of its nature?). Anyhow, if you need me to post pictures of it on hover, and non-hover, lemme know.